# Is it possible to put the LocalDb on WORKGROUP network and connect remotely with a C# application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localdb, workgroup

I hope you're all doing well. I'm creating a Desktop Application for a friend using C#, which will be installed on 2 different PCs. Both users will need to connect to a Database, but the problem is that they don't have SQL Server installed on their machines. I'm thinking of creating a LocalDb with Visual Studio and put it on a WORKGROUP Network which gathers both machines so that they can connect to it remotely. I still did not try it, I want to know first if it's possible or not.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, just use SQL Server Express.

Localdb uses named pipes only.

Answer (score 0):

just use one of the 2 computers as the host for the SQL server and open the firewall port allowing for TCP connections when from the LAN network

You can use the computer name to connect if you enabled network discovery, else you will need to use the IP address (make sure it always has the same)

[image]